# How can I use variables only once with 'on mouseenter' and 'on mouseleave'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have multiple objects with different sizes that I want each to display additional box `on mouseenter` and hide `on mouseleave`. I have a jquery script that does it perfectly, my only concern is that I am repeating variables twice and something tells me that this can be done without repeating myself.

Problem is they both are strongly based on `$(this)` core element, so I can't make variables global. My guess was that I should put them withing the element container function, right before `on mouseenter` and `on mouseleave` are called, but syntax wise I have no idea how to do it. But again, I might be terribly wrong on that.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.box-options').hide();   

    var $boxModule = $('div.box');

    $boxModule.on({

        mouseenter: function() {

            var $this = $(this),                               // repeat                
                $options = $this.find('div.options'),          // repeat
                $optionsBox = $this.find('div.options-box');   // repeat

            var boxHeight = $this.height(),                    // repeat
                boxWidth = $this.width(),                      // repeat
                optionsBoxHeight = $optionsBox.outerHeight();  // repeat

            if ( // statement referring to variables above } 
            else {  // statement referring to variables above };            

            $options.fadeIn(200).addClass('shadow').css({"height" : boxHeight + optionsBoxHeight});
            $optionsBox.delay(100).fadeIn(200).css({"top" : boxHeight}, 200);
        },

        mouseleave: function() {

            var $this = $(this),                                 // repeat
                $options = $this.find('div.options'),          // repeat
                $optionsBox = $this.find('div.options-box');   // repeat

            var boxHeight = $this.height(),                    // repeat
                boxWidth = $this.width(),                      // repeat
                optionsBoxHeight = $optionsBox.outerHeight();  // repeat

            $optionsBox.hide().css({"top" : boxHeight});
            $options.hide().removeClass('shadow').css({"height" : boxHeight}, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously the code contains more lines, but the important part is variables marked as `// repeat`. Does anyone know how I can re-structure the code to make variables be written only once?

UPDATE: I updated the code to describe logic better. Just to make it clear, on each page there are also multiple objects with identical classes, structure and size, only difference is content (text) within and id number.

Comment: I guess you could use `$( selector ).hover( handlerInOut);` but you would need to modificate in some way your logic. Now you should have posted all the `Etc..` relevant parts of your code

Comment: Thanks Wolff, I added missing info

Answer (score 1):

Use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function and for variables declare them before hovering event like you have done for `$boxModule`.

Calling

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

is shorthand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Comment: `hover` method btw accepts handlerInOut: `$( selector .hover( handlerInOut )` where type of event can be filtered using `event.type`. Now depending logic inside each handler, it could be a easier solution but hard to say because OP posted code with some '...'

Answer (score 0):

#### You can declare var outside on event like :

```
$('div.box').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $options = $this.find('div.options'),
        $optionsBox = $this.find('div.options-box'),
        boxHeight = $this.height();

    $this.on({
        mouseenter: function() {...}
        mouseleave: function() {...}
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this will produce an confusion when more than one `div.box` is presented on the page and we would like to operate only on one of them.

Comment: I think, We can use each() method and can declare variables within each() method using var $this = $(this), $options = $this.find('div.options') etc.

Comment: Well, in the each loop you are attaching two event handlers every iteration. So every `div.box` would have as many handlers as you have boxes times 2. I doubt it is optimal solution of that problem.

PS. If you have to change your answer don't delete the previous answer, since my first comment was about totally different code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a `function` that return an `object` that you can use in every handler?

```
var calcVars =  function(){
    var $this = $(this),                               
            $options = $this.find('div.options'),      
            $optionsBox = $this.find('div.options-box');

        var boxHeight = $this.height(),                 
            boxWidth = $this.width(),                   
            optionsBoxHeight = $optionsBox.outerHeight();
    return {
        boxHeight: boxHeight, 
        //every other variable you need outside
    }

$boxModule.on({

    firstEvent: function() {

        var object = calcVars.call(this);

        object.calculatedProperty.doSomething();

        //other code 
    },    

    secondEvent: function() {

        var object = calcVars.call(this);

        object.anotherCalculatedProperty.doSomething();

        //other code 
    } 
})
```

or you can do:

```
$boxModule.on("anEvent anotherEvent", function(event) {
 /*
    var declarations
  */  
  var $this = $(this), 
      //etc..

  if(event.type == "anEvent"){
     doStuff();
  else if(event.type == "anotherEvent"){
     doOtherStuff();
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for repetition in that code would be to create an external function to get some of the information from the element passed as an argument.

For example:

```
function options($element) {
  return $element.find('div.options');
}
```

The same goes for every other property based on $(this).

Then you can just use your options inside your event handler as such: `options($this).fadeIn(200)`

Hope this helps to clean your code.